# How to test lambda function in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, mockk

I am testing my function. Inside on function parameter I am passing the `Lambda` with `Arrangement.Vertical`. I tried some piece of code but it giving me error. I am adding my function here

**PairViewModel**

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class PairViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    var isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    fun setBluetoothEnable(newValue: Boolean) {
        isBluetoothEnabled = newValue
    }

    fun isBluetoothEnable(
        bluetoothOn: () -> Arrangement.Vertical,
        bluetoothOff: () -> Arrangement.Vertical
    ): Arrangement.Vertical {
        return if (isBluetoothEnabled) {
            bluetoothOn()
        } else {
            bluetoothOff()
        }
    }
}
```

**PairViewModelTest**

```
class PairViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val testInstantTaskExecutorRule: TestRule = TestMainCoroutineRule()

    private val subject by lazy { spyk(PairViewModel()) }
    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        MockKAnnotations.init(this, relaxed = true)
    }
    
    @Test
    fun `isBluetoothEnable - WHEN isBluetoothEnabled is false THEN should call lamda bluetoothOn`() {
        // STUBBING
        val mockedUnit = mockk<() -> Arrangement.Vertical>(relaxed = true)
        every { subject.isBluetoothEnabled } returns false

        // EXECUTION
        subject.isBluetoothEnable(mockedUnit, mockedUnit)

        // VERIFICATION
        verify {
            mockedUnit()
        }
    }
}
```

**Error**

```
class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.PairViewModel.isBluetoothEnable(PairViewModel.kt:136)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.MethodCall.call(MethodCall.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.SelfCallEliminatorCallable.call(SelfCallEliminatorCallable.kt:14)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:95)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper.access$handleOriginalCall(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:18)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1$invocation$$inlined$stdFunctions$lambda$1.invoke(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:27)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub$handleInvocation$originalPlusToString$1.invoke(MockKStub.kt:230)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.SpyKStub.defaultAnswer(SpyKStub.kt:15)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.answer(MockKStub.kt:42)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.states.AnsweringState.call(AnsweringState.kt:16)
    at io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.call(CommonCallRecorder.kt:53)
    at io.mockk.impl.stub.MockKStub.handleInvocation(MockKStub.kt:266)
    at io.mockk.impl.instantiation.JvmMockFactoryHelper$mockHandler$1.invocation(JvmMockFactoryHelper.kt:23)
    at io.mockk.proxy.jvm.advice.Interceptor.call(Interceptor.kt:21)
    at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.PairViewModel.isBluetoothEnable(PairViewModel.kt:135)
    at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.PairViewModelTest.isBluetoothEnable - WHEN isBluetoothEnabled is false THEN should call lamda bluetoothOn(PairViewModelTest.kt:512)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at com.abc.app.utils.TestMainCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TestMainCoroutineRule.kt:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Does anyone what is the problem in here? Thanks

**UDPATE**

I tried to follow this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74573933/11560810). But still doesn’t solve the issue.

```
@Test
    fun `isBluetoothEnable`() {
        // STUBBING
        every { subject.isBluetoothEnabled } returns true
        val lambdaUnit = { Arrangement.Top }
        val lambdaSlot = slot<(() -> Arrangement.Vertical)>()

        // EXECUTION
        subject.isBluetoothEnable(lambdaUnit, lambdaUnit)

        // VERIFICATION
        verify {
            capture(lambdaSlot)
        }
        lambdaSlot.captured.invoke()
        verify {
            Arrangement.Top
        }
    }
```

**Error**

```
Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [slotCapture<Function0>()]
io.mockk.MockKException: Failed matching mocking signature for

left matchers: [slotCapture<Function0>()]
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.SignatureMatcherDetector.detect(SignatureMatcherDetector.kt:99)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.signMatchers(RecordingState.kt:39)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.states.RecordingState.round(RecordingState.kt:31)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.recording.CommonCallRecorder.round(CommonCallRecorder.kt:50)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.eval.RecordedBlockEvaluator.record(RecordedBlockEvaluator.kt:63)
    at app//io.mockk.impl.eval.VerifyBlockEvaluator.verify(VerifyBlockEvaluator.kt:30)
    at app//io.mockk.MockKDsl.internalVerify(API.kt:119)
    at app//io.mockk.MockKKt.verify(MockK.kt:149)
    at app//io.mockk.MockKKt.verify$default(MockK.kt:146)
    at app//com.abc.app.bloodpressurePair.iewModelTest.isBluetoothEnable(PairViewModelTest.kt:576)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at app//org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:56)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at app//org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at app//com.abc.app.utils.TestMainCoroutineRule$apply$1.evaluate(TestMainCoroutineRule.kt:26)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner$1.evaluate(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:100)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:366)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:103)
    at app//org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:63)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$4.run(ParentRunner.java:331)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:79)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:329)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$100(ParentRunner.java:66)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:293)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:306)
    at app//org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:413)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.runTestClass(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.JUnitTestClassExecutor.execute(JUnitTestClassExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junit.AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(AbstractJUnitTestClassProcessor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.processTestClass(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:51)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base@11.0.13/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@11.0.13/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.processTestClass(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$2.run(TestWorker.java:176)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
```

Comment: Show us the implementation of `PairViewModel`

Comment: @Steyrix I added my code. Please have a look

Comment: Please correct used wording -> it's `LamBda`, not `Lamda`

Comment: Sorry for that.. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one:

`PairViewModel`

```
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.runtime.getValue
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.setValue

class PairViewModel : BaseViewModel() {

    var isBluetoothEnabled by mutableStateOf(false)
        private set

    var uiState by mutableStateOf<BluetoothConnectionUIState>(BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial)
        private set

    fun bluetoothArrangement(
        on: () -> Arrangement.Vertical,
        off: () -> Arrangement.Vertical
    ): Arrangement.Vertical {
        return if (isBluetoothEnabled || uiState == BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial) {
            on.invoke()
        } else {
            off.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

`PairViewModelTest`

```
    class PairViewModelTest {

    @get:Rule
    val testInstantTaskExecutorRule: TestRule = TestMainCoroutineRule()

    private val subject by lazy { spyk(PairViewModel()) }

    @Test
    fun `bluetoothArrangement - WHEN isBluetoothEnabled THEN should invoke bluetooth on`() {
        // STUBBING
        val mockOn = mockk<() -> Arrangement.Vertical>(relaxed = true)
        every { mockOn.invoke() } returns mockk()
        every { subject.isBluetoothEnabled } returns true

        // EXECUTION
        subject.bluetoothArrangement(mockOn, mockk())

        // VERIFICATION
        verify {
            mockOn.invoke()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `bluetoothArrangement - WHEN uiState is Initial THEN should should invoke bluetooth on`() {
        // STUBBING
        val mockOn = mockk<() -> Arrangement.Vertical>(relaxed = true)
        every { mockOn.invoke() } returns mockk()
        every { subject.uiState } returns BluetoothConnectionUIState.Initial

        // EXECUTION
        subject.bluetoothArrangement(mockOn, mockk())

        // VERIFICATION
        verify {
            mockOn.invoke()
        }
    }

    @Test
    fun `bluetoothArrangement - WHEN uiState is not Initial & is not isBluetoothEnabled THEN should should invoke bluetooth off`() {
        // STUBBING
        val mockOff = mockk<() -> Arrangement.Vertical>(relaxed = true)
        every { mockOff.invoke() } returns mockk()
        every { subject.isBluetoothEnabled } returns false
        every { subject.uiState } returns BluetoothConnectionUIState.ScanningDevice()

        // EXECUTION
        subject.bluetoothArrangement(mockk(), mockOff)

        // VERIFICATION
        verify {
            mockOff.invoke()
        }
    }
}
```

Just to explain why, the error:

```
class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.lang.Object cannot be cast to class androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical (java.lang.Object is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement$Vertical is in unnamed module of loader 'app')
    at com.abc.app.bloodpressure.PairViewModel.isBluetoothEnable(PairViewModel.kt:136)
```

when you are calling `on.invoke()` this method should return a valid vertical, you are getting this error cause U didn't set the return for invoke method.

the "trick" is here `every { mockOn.invoke() } returns mockk()`

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to test that lambda does the work.
Make your lambda do something. There is no need to mock it, since mocking is used when you want some object to return something specific you want, independently from any possible conditions.
You probably want to use `slot`

```
// Please match the type () -> Arrangement.Vertical , below is raw example
val lambdaUnit = { example.exampleWork() } 
val lambdaSlot = slot<(() -> Arrangement.Vertical)>()

subject.isBluetoothEnable(lambdaUnit, lambdaUnit)

verify { capture(lambdaSlot) }

lambdaSlot.captured.invoke()

verify { example.exampleWork() }
```

Comment: I tried your code but still causing issue. I was updated in my question. Can you please guide me?

Comment: The problem is you trying to verify not a call but value. Try to put some method call in lambda and verify it, or try to wrap `Arrangement.Top` in curly braces

Comment: You mean double curly braces like this `{{ Arrangement.Top }}`?

Comment: I mean wrap it in verify block